# How can I change navigation bar for added subview in ios

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar

I have one parent view controller whose navigation bar contains a Menu button and a search bar.

After pressing the Menu button one new viewController is added as subview. I want to remove existing search bar and I want to place a label. I am not  able to access the parent's navigation controller from the child.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Add some code about adding subview, it will help to understand your issue.

Comment: Hi,I had read some documents and come to know that navigation bar get loaded at viewconreoller's load time.As I was adding subview i couldn't change parents navigation bar.So I "Pushed" child view instead of "addSubview".And it worked..Thanks..